# Understanding binary code

Tags: binary, numbers, primitive-types

I have watched a lot of youtube videos about binary code, but I don't understand this: If an 8 bit-system looks like this: `1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128` how does a 16 bit-system look like?
like this: `1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048 4096 8192 16384 32768` and what are the advantages of `more bits` the cpu can understand more data at once, I mean because there are more bits you can pass more data at once? Can someone help me a little bit please?

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulties understanding?

Comment: Somehow I doubt that understanding complex matters of computing architecture and youtube video tutorials are compatible... Read a couple of good books, maybe start with Wikipedia, and do some thinking of your own; those will probably get you further than any video.

Comment: how that string looks like, if I'm right..if for the 8 bit-system is this `1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128` and for the 16 bit-system is this: `1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048 4096 8192 16384 32768`

Comment: are you asking about the differences between binary and hex?  Binary is simply a series of 0's and 1's where as Hex is generally 0-F where F = 15.  in Binary it takes many more digits to represent 16 (0001 0000) than hex (10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand what you're asking, because you're not very clear.
I believe you ask about the difference between, say, a 16-bit computer, and a 32-bit computer.
Here, the main difference is the size of a register. A 16-bit computer has 16-bit registers, which can hold numbers between 0 and 65536 (or, if treating them as signed, between -32768 and 32767). The computer can't directly manipulate larger numbers. If it wants, for example, to multiply 100,000*100,000, it can't do it directly (it can use 3 16-bit multiplication, but this is slower).
Another effect is the amount of memory that can be accessed. Pointers are stored in registers, so a pointer in a 16-bit system can point to one of 65536 locations, which limits the memory size to 64KB. In 32-bits, you can access 4GB, and in 64-bits much much more.
Virtual memory somewhat changes things, but this is still essentially true.